Missing \endgroup inserted (tabular) and not in outer par mode
I structured the first set of figures after the second one. The second set works. The first set doesn't. Why not?
Sometimes the error I get is "not in outer par mode"; sometimes it's "missing \endgroup inserted".
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,openright,oneside,final]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

Lots of other text, then...

%%% THIS THROWS AN ERROR %%%
%\begin{figure}[h]
%\centering
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
%  \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
%          \begin{figure}[H]
%              \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image}
%           \end{figure} 
%&&
%          \begin{figure}[H]
%              \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image}
%          \end{figure} 
%&&
%          \begin{figure}[H]
%              \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image}
%          \end{figure} \\
%$P(20 < X < 30)$ & = & $P(X < 30)$ & - & $P(X < 20)$\\
%\end{tabular}
%\caption{A useful trick.} 
%\label{Trick2}
%\end{figure}

Text after the first one

%%% THIS WORKS %%%

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
  \begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillA \fillB
        \end{venndiagram2sets}
        &&
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillA 
        \end{venndiagram2sets}
&&
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillB
        \end{venndiagram2sets}
&&
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillACapB
        \end{venndiagram2sets}\\

$P(A \cup B)  $ & = & $P(A) \ \ $ & + & $P(B) \ \ $ & - & $P(A \cap B)$\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{The Addition Rule.} 
\label{AdditionRuleFig}
\end{figure}

Text after the second one.

\end{document}


the structure is not at all the same. in the first case you have nested figure within tabular within figure. you can't use figure inside figure or tabular. if you want subfigures, look at subcaption or subfig. or just don't use figure at all and the images will be H anyway.

This looks very much like a XY problem. IMHO your real question is something like: How to align images and equations side by side. If I'm wrong and you really want to know what's wrong with the commented code: You cannot use floats (like figure or table) inside floats. And floats inside other environments can float outside these environments and therefore usually do not use the settings of these environments. And therefore using figure inside a tabular does not make sense. Note: h is only here if it fits.

h will be automatically changed into ht so the float still has somewhere to go even if it can't fit here.

The structure of the two cases is not at all the same.
In the first case you have nested figure, which is a float environment, within tabular within figure. You can't use figure inside figure or tabular. The former will give an error; the latter will just fail to work as expected because the figure will probably not stay in the tabular.
A float is an environment which tells LaTeX to place the contents in a good place, which will not typically be here. Putting content into such an environment explicitly tells LaTeX to let it move - 'float' - elsewhere. If you don't want something to get moved, it is best not to use a float at all. If you just want a caption, use \captionof from the capt-of or caption packages.
But in this case, you don't use a caption inside the nested figures, so just removing the figure environment may be sufficient.
If you want subfigures, look at the packages subcaption or subfig. Else don't use figure at all and the images will be H anyway.
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,openright,oneside,final]{book}   
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{venndiagram}

\begin{document}

Lots of other text, then...

%%% This works also
\begin{figure}[h]% will be changed to 'ht'
  \centering
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
  \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image}
    &&
    \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image}
    &&
    \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image}
    \\
    $P(20 < X < 30)$ & = & $P(X < 30)$ & - & $P(X < 20)$\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A useful trick.}
  \label{Trick2}
\end{figure}

Text after the first one

%%% THIS WORKS %%%

\begin{figure}[h]% will be changed to 'ht'
  \centering
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
  \begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
      \fillA \fillB
    \end{venndiagram2sets}
    &&
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
      \fillA
    \end{venndiagram2sets}
    &&
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
      \fillB
    \end{venndiagram2sets}
    &&
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
      \fillACapB
    \end{venndiagram2sets}\\

    $P(A \cup B)  $ & = & $P(A) \ \ $ & + & $P(B) \ \ $ & - & $P(A \cap B)$\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{The Addition Rule.}
  \label{AdditionRuleFig}
\end{figure}

Text after the second one.

\end{document}

The result is a bit odd looking, so I'm not sure it is the intended result, but it does compile without error. (There are warnings e.g. about h, but no errors.)
